# Executing win32 file ( using UpdateResource winapi ) in unix

Tags: windows, linux, executable

I guess it is impossible, but I will ask it anyway. I have a Windows application that executes `BeginUpdateResource` / `UpdateResource` / `EndUpdateResource`

Can I somehow execute this on Linux/Unix?  Its server-side, so no GUI emulator could be running.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure exactly what can be achieved with [Wine](http://www.winehq.org/documentation), but that might be a way to go if you have the source code for the application you want to run. See also [Will Wine run only under X, or can it run in character mode?](http://wiki.winehq.org/WikiToDo).

Another alternative is to re-write the functionality.

Answer (score 0):

I would not recommend it unless you are using **Wine** which is not an emulator but a re-implementation/binding of the Win32 API on Linux and a handler for Windows executables.

If you want to do things like this, port your application to **C#/.NET** and use the Mono runtime on the Linux system..

In short, **dont**